# GEE vs Marginal Models: Are they the same? How are they different?

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, generalized-estimating-equations

In Agresti's "Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models", section 9.1.3 unambiguously states that "GLMMs imply marginal models" and demonstrates in a few lines how "averaging over the random effects" gives use the marginal model. This makes sense. In section 9.7 he fits some data to illustrate "marginal models and GLMMs." However, he uses gee() from library(gee) in R to demonstrate the marginal model.

This leads to my broader question. If GEEs are the same as marginal models, why do GEEs seem to have their own literature, estimation methods (I think?), packages, etc.? And if they are different, can you provide an overview of the difference? In fact, they have so much extra material that I'm pretty sure they are more than just marginal models.

Any thoughts welcome, and I always love a good paper. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GEE *is* a marginal model. Unlike "plain" regression, such as OLS or GLMS for independent data, the GEE estimates the variance structure which accounts for correlation structures.

However the point estimates are the same as with the models for independent data. The inference is also often from sandwich variance estimation which sandwiches the expected information (A matrix or bread) and observed information (B matrix or meat) to calculate robust error estimation. The sandwich is a powerful estimator even for independent data, providing heteroscedasticity consistent estimates of the standard error.

Unfortunately, the literature on GEE hasn't, in my opinion, been well codified until somewhat recently. Two references come to mind:

Longitudinal Data Analysis - Diggle, Heagerty, Liang and Zeger (the latter two authors pioneered the GEE model).

Also recently Bayesian and Frequentist Regression Methods by Jonathan Wakefield